# Jquery скролл не работает в IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет!

Такая ситуация как написано в теме, в остальных браузерах всё работает как надо (на мобильных в том числе).

Код:

```js
$("button").click(function () {
    $("html").animate({scrollTop:$('.wrapperContacts').position().top}, 1000);
    $(".tempPayMessage").css('display','flex');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Реализация на сайте:
http://med-point.com.ua/

Comment: Зачем-то в такой анимации писался селектор $("html, body").animate ... . Не помню зачем, но может для этого

Comment: Работает!!! Спасибо!!!